# JQuery floating images?

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create a series of floating images in JQuery.  The idea is I will have photos of people holding balloons and these images will float around a box (928px × 232px) and slowly drift out of the the box (overflow:hidden) to be replaced by another image drifting into the box.
So there might be 10 images in total but only 3 in the box at any one time.

A tricky thing to explain but I hope you get the idea.
Is there anything out there thats somewhere near to what I'm after?  I'm not an expert in JQuery but can hopefully adapt existing code.

The closest thing I can find is this:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/flyimage.htm

I'd prefer something in JQuery as its much easier to animate.

Comment: Yoshi made this example in an earlier post http://jsfiddle.net/Whu2m/1/ - you could then add it going from side to side random :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Marco Johannesen for his comment above.  The example given should be enough to get me started :)

http://jsfiddle.net/Whu2m/1/